# List length check not working in Sudoku checker

Tags: python

I want to write some Python code to check that whether a matrix accords with the rule of Sudoku. My code is presented below:

```
correct = [[1,2,3],
           [2,3,1],
           [3,1,2]]

incorrect = [[1,2,3,4],
             [2,3,1,3],
             [3,1,2,3],
             [4,4,4,4]]

incorrect2 = [[1,2,3,4],
             [2,3,1,4],
             [4,1,2,3],
             [3,4,1,2]]

incorrect3 = [[1,2,3,4,5],
              [2,3,1,5,6],
              [4,5,2,1,3],
              [3,4,5,2,1],
              [5,6,4,3,2]]

incorrect4 = [['a','b','c'],
              ['b','c','a'],
              ['c','a','b']]

incorrect5 = [ [1, 1.5],
               [1.5, 1]]

def check_sudoku(matrix):
    n = len(matrix)
    # check each row
    i, j = 0, 0
    while i < n:
        checked = []
        while j < n:
            if matrix[i][j] not in checked:
                checked.append(matrix[i][j])
            j += 1
        if len(checked) < n:
            return False
        i += 1
    # check each column
    i, j = 0, 0
    while i < n:
        checked = []
        while j < n:
            if matrix[j][i] not in checked:
                len(checked)
                checked.append(matrix[j][i])
            j += 1
        if len(checked) < n:
            return False
        i += 1

    return True

# the output should look like this:
print(check_sudoku(incorrect))
#>>> False

print(check_sudoku(correct))
#>>> True

print(check_sudoku(incorrect2))
#>>> False

print(check_sudoku(incorrect3))
#>>> False

print(check_sudoku(incorrect4))
#>>> False

print(check_sudoku(incorrect5))
#>>> False
```

But here's a weird problem in the if statement. After the two inner while loops, the statement "len(checked)" evaluates to 0 which should not be like that. I don't know what happened.

Comment: "After the inner while loop" which one?

Comment: The inner while loop

Comment: You should consider splitting up your `check_sudoku` to more functions.

Comment: @vished_shell the first inner while loop

Comment: You have two inner while loops in your code.

Comment: using `while` here is not optimal to begin with. You know the iterations required before you enter the loop and you become prone to errors by using it. replacing it with an `for i in range(n)` would solve most of your problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem with your code is that you don't reset `j` to zero at the end of the inner loops. So when you try to check the second row (and subsequent rows) the `j` values are too big. The same problem occurs when you're testing the columns.

However, there are other problems with this logic, eg `[5,6,4,3,2]` tests as ok because it has 5 unique elements, but they aren't the right elements, they should be some permutation of `[1,2,3,4,5]`. Similarly, the matrix of strings and the matrix containing 1.5 are treated as valid instead of invalid.

But anyway, here's a repaired version that fixes the `j` initialization issue mentioned earlier.

```
grids = [
    [[1,2,3],
    [2,3,1],
    [3,1,2]],

    [[1,2,3,4],
    [2,3,1,3],
    [3,1,2,3],
    [4,4,4,4]],

    [[1,2,3,4],
    [2,3,1,4],
    [4,1,2,3],
    [3,4,1,2]],

    [[1,2,3,4,5],
    [2,3,1,5,6],
    [4,5,2,1,3],
    [3,4,5,2,1],
    [5,6,4,3,2]],

    [['a','b','c'],
    ['b','c','a'],
    ['c','a','b']],

    [[1, 1.5],
    [1.5, 1]],
]

def check_sudoku(matrix):
    n = len(matrix)
    # check each row
    i = 0
    while i < n:
        checked = []
        j = 0
        while j < n:
            if matrix[i][j] not in checked:
                checked.append(matrix[i][j])
            j += 1
        if len(checked) < n:
            return False
        i += 1
    # check each column
    i = 0
    while i < n:
        checked = []
        j = 0
        while j < n:
            if matrix[j][i] not in checked:
                checked.append(matrix[j][i])
            j += 1
        if len(checked) < n:
            return False
        i += 1

    return True

for g in grids:
    for row in g:
        print(row)
    print(check_sudoku(g), end='\n\n')
```

**output**

```
[1, 2, 3]
[2, 3, 1]
[3, 1, 2]
True

[1, 2, 3, 4]
[2, 3, 1, 3]
[3, 1, 2, 3]
[4, 4, 4, 4]
False

[1, 2, 3, 4]
[2, 3, 1, 4]
[4, 1, 2, 3]
[3, 4, 1, 2]
False

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[2, 3, 1, 5, 6]
[4, 5, 2, 1, 3]
[3, 4, 5, 2, 1]
[5, 6, 4, 3, 2]
True

['a', 'b', 'c']
['b', 'c', 'a']
['c', 'a', 'b']
True

[1, 1.5]
[1.5, 1]
True
```

---

Here's an alternative strategy which is more compact, and (potentially) faster because it uses Python's fast `all` function in conjunction with sets to do the testing. This version *only* considers a matrix to be valid if it contains the integers from 1 to *n*, where *n* is the size of the matrix.

```
grids = [
    [[1,2,3],
    [2,3,1],
    [3,1,2]],

    [[1,2,3,4],
    [2,3,1,3],
    [3,1,2,3],
    [4,4,4,4]],

    [[1,2,3,4],
    [2,3,1,4],
    [4,1,2,3],
    [3,4,1,2]],

    [[1,2,3,4,5],
    [2,3,1,5,6],
    [4,5,2,1,3],
    [3,4,5,2,1],
    [5,6,4,3,2]],

    [['a','b','c'],
    ['b','c','a'],
    ['c','a','b']],

    [[1, 1.5],
    [1.5, 1]],
]

def check_sudoku(matrix):
    full = set(range(1, len(matrix) + 1))
    return (all(set(row) == full for row in matrix)
        and all(set(row) == full for row in zip(*matrix)))

for g in grids:
    for row in g:
        print(row)
    print(check_sudoku(g), end='\n\n')
```

**output**

```
[1, 2, 3]
[2, 3, 1]
[3, 1, 2]
True

[1, 2, 3, 4]
[2, 3, 1, 3]
[3, 1, 2, 3]
[4, 4, 4, 4]
False

[1, 2, 3, 4]
[2, 3, 1, 4]
[4, 1, 2, 3]
[3, 4, 1, 2]
False

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[2, 3, 1, 5, 6]
[4, 5, 2, 1, 3]
[3, 4, 5, 2, 1]
[5, 6, 4, 3, 2]
False

['a', 'b', 'c']
['b', 'c', 'a']
['c', 'a', 'b']
False

[1, 1.5]
[1.5, 1]
False
```

This part:

```
all(set(row) == full for row in zip(*matrix))
```

verifies that the columns are valid because `zip(*matrix)` essentially creates a transposed version of `matrix`.

The `all` function is quite efficient, and it stops testing as soon as it encounters a false-ish result. On a similar note, the `and` operator short-circuits, which means that the columns aren't checked if the rows aren't valid.

Answer (score 0):

You don't zeroing `j` variable in inner loops (both inner loops).

```
i, j = 0, 0
while i < n:
    checked = []
    j = 0 # you need set j to zero in each run
          # if you don't do this: j will be equal to n in second run
    while j < n:
        if matrix[i][j] not in checked:
            checked.append(matrix[i][j])
        j += 1
    if len(checked) < n:
        return False
    i += 1
```

Also you need to check sub matrices.

Comment: you don't have to check the diagonals in sudokus. just the sub-matrices apart from the rows and columns. And your code returns `[False, True, False, True, True, True]`

Comment: @Ev.Kounis The quiz just need us to check the cols and rows.Thank you anyway.

Comment: Remove part about diagonals. Code return `True` for `incorrect3`,4,5 because it don't checks everything. Kevin asks only why `checked` is empty, hi don't ask to write full sudoku checker.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're not initializing `j` properly for the two inner while loops. Here's your code and the indicated modifications to make it work:

```
def check_sudoku(matrix):
    n = len(matrix)
    # check each row
#    i, j = 0, 0
    i = 0
    while i < n:
        j = 0  # added
        checked = []
        while j < n:
            if matrix[i][j] not in checked:
                checked.append(matrix[i][j])
            j += 1
        if len(checked) < n:
            return False
        i += 1
    # check each column
#    i, j = 0, 0
    i = 0
    while i < n:
        j = 0  # added
        checked = []
        while j < n:
            if matrix[j][i] not in checked:
                checked.append(matrix[j][i])
            j += 1
        if len(checked) < n:
            return False
        i += 1

    return True
```